# python string search replace

Tags: python, string, search, replace

```
SSViewer::set_theme('bullsorbit');
```

this my string. I want search in string `"SSViewer::set_theme('bullsorbit'); "` and replace `'bullsorbit'` with another string. `'bullsorbit'` string is dynamically changing.

Comment: what does *dynamically changing* mean?

Answer (score 3):

Not in a situation to be able to test this so you may need to fiddle with the Regular Expression (they may be errors in it.)

```
import re
re.sub("SSViewer::set_theme\('[a-z]+'\)", "SSViewer::set_theme('whatever')", my_string)
```

Is this what you want?

Just tested it, this is some sample output:

```
my_string = """Some file with some other junk
SSViewer::set_theme('bullsorbit');
SSViewer::set_theme('another');
Something else"""

import re
replaced = re.sub("SSViewer::set_theme\('[a-z]+'\)", "SSViewer::set_theme('whatever')", my_string)
print replaced
```

produces:

```
Some file with some other junk
SSViewer::set_theme('whatever');
SSViewer::set_theme('whatever');
Something else
```

if you want to do it to a file:

```
my_string = open('myfile', 'r').read()
```

Comment: thank u for reply .. it is file .. i want read file and search for that string and replace what ever

Comment: That will replace everything with `my_string`. Check this by running it in the interactive console

Comment: import re
file_read = open("/var/www/rajaneesh/mysite/_config.php", "r")
contents = file_read.read()
file_read.close()

this my code
i want search that string "SSViewer::set_theme\('whatever')" file and replace that string with new string

Comment: You want to find 'bullsorbit' from the pattern "SSViewer::set_theme('bullsorbit');" and replace all occurrences of 'bullsorbit' thereafter with another string? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Be clear that this only works for lower case [a-z] If you want it to catch other characters you will need to tweak the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
>> my_string = "SSViewer::set_theme('bullsorbit');"
>>> import re
>>> change = re.findall(r"SSViewer::set_theme\('(\w*)'\);",my_string)
>>> my_string.replace(change[0],"blah")
"SSViewer::set_theme('blah');"
```

its not elegant but it works. the findall will return a dictionary of items that are inside the ('') and then replaces them. If you can get sub to work then that may look nicer but this will definitely work

Comment: Consider this: "SSViewer::set_theme('theme')" would be replaced with "SSViewer::set_blah('blah')"

Answer (score 0):

```
st = "SSViewer::set_theme('"
for line in open("file.txt"):
    line=line.strip()
    if st in line:
        a = line[ :line.index(st)+len(st)]
        b = line [line.index(st)+len(st): ]
        i = b.index("')")
        b = b[i:]
        print a + "newword" + b
```

Answer (score 0):

while your explanation is not entirely clear, I think you might make some use of the following:

```
open(fname).read().replace('bullsorbit', 'new_string')
```

Comment: i thought he meant bullsorbit is changing dynamically, so the above might not be what he needs.

Comment: what exactly *changing dynamically* means? run it with another string, `'bullsorbit2'`.