# how do find and replace string with python

Tags: python

There is an string like this

```
100Usable by Everybody: Design Principles for Accessibility on Mac OS X 101What's New in Cocoa Touch 102What's New in Foundation for iOS 4 103iPad and iPhone User Interface Design 104Designing Apps with Scroll Views 308Developing Your App with Xcode 4 309Advanced Performance Analysis with Instruments 419OpenGL ES Tuning and Optimization 420OpenGL for Mac OS X 421Incorporating the Camera and Photo Library in your App 422Taking Advantage of Multiple GPUs
```

I want to find all number substring, so I get an set of number string，one of them will be like ‘100’. Then I modify it, append '\n- ' before it. So finally I will get an string like this

```
- 100 Usable by Everybody: Design Principles for Accessibility on Mac OS X 
- 101 What's New in Cocoa Touch 
- 102 What's New in Foundation for iOS 4 
- 103 iPad and iPhone User Interface Design 
- 104 Designing Apps with Scroll Views
- 308 Developing Your App with Xcode 4 
- 309 Advanced Performance Analysis with Instruments 
- 419 OpenGL ES Tuning and Optimization 
- 420 OpenGL for Mac OS X 
- 421 Incorporating the Camera and Photo Library in your App 
- 422 Taking Advantage of Multiple GPUs
```

How can i do this with python, please help. Thanks very much.

---

After find the number substring, I use it. For example, I find '100', then it will be replace with '\n - 100 '.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python string search replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184119/python-string-search-replace)

Comment: What's the logic here, why does it not add a line break at `iOS 4`? 4 is a number too.

Comment: Is the marker always 3 digits?

Comment: @cdarke Yes! How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the number is always 3 digits (since you have other numbers embedded in the data):

```
data = "100Usable by Everybody: Design Principles for Accessibility on Mac OS X 101What's New in Cocoa Touch 102What's New in Foundation for iOS 4 103iPad and iPhone User Interface Design 104Designing Apps with Scroll Views 105Adopting Multitasking on iPhone OS, Part 1 106Understanding Document Interaction Controller 107Cocoa Tips and Tricks"

import re

new_data = re.sub(r'(\d{3})', '\n- \\1 ', data)
print(new_data)
```

Gives:

```
- 100 Usable by Everybody: Design Principles for Accessibility on Mac OS X 
- 101 What's New in Cocoa Touch 
- 102 What's New in Foundation for iOS 4 
- 103 iPad and iPhone User Interface Design 
- 104 Designing Apps with Scroll Views 
- 105 Adopting Multitasking on iPhone OS, Part 1 
- 106 Understanding Document Interaction Controller 
- 107 Cocoa Tips and Tricks
```

Comment: So nice solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: OK, one caveat:  you must guarantee that the text data does not contain 3 digits anywhere!

Comment: The text data always contain 3 digits. Thanks again.